# Adding columns to a table on MySQL and making the fields of these columns such that the user can input marks

Tags: php, mysql, wamp64

I cloned an opensource project called opensis and I want to modify it to suit my use. In the table called student_report_card_grades i added the columns for CA marks and exam marks since this table enabled the user to either enter a grade for the student or the final percentage for a student in that subject. I have succeeded to create these fields but the function which i defined which is allow a user input CA marks and Exam marks is not working as I tested the software and I am unable to add CA marks and exam marks

I defined two functions makeCAMarks and _makeExamMarks function which is supposed to make the fields in such a way that the user input CA marks as well as exam marks but my function is not working as I am not able to input these marks. Here is a snippet of my code below

```
   $columns = array('FULL_NAME' =>_student,
 'STUDENT_ID' =>_studentId, 
 'CA_MARKS' => 'CA Marks',
 'EXAM_MARKS' => 'Exam Marks',
);

$columns += array(
    'CA_MARKS' => '_makeCAMarks',
    'EXAM_MARKS' => '_makeExamMarks',
);

if ($_REQUEST['include_inactive'] == 'Y')
    $columns += array('ACTIVE' =>_schoolStatus,
     'ACTIVE_SCHEDULE' =>_courseStatus,
    );
if ($_REQUEST['use_percents'] != 'true')
    $columns += array('GRADE_PERCENT' =>_percent,
     'REPORT_CARD_GRADE' =>_assignGrade,
    );
elseif ($not_graded)
    $columns += array('GRADE_PERCENT' =>_assignPercent,
);
else
    $columns += array('REPORT_CARD_GRADE' =>_grade,
     'GRADE_PERCENT' =>_assignPercent,
    );



if (substr($_REQUEST['mp'], 0, 1) != 'E' && GetMP($_REQUEST['mp'], 'DOES_COMMENTS') == 'Y') {
    foreach ($commentsA_RET as $value)
        $columns += array('CA' . $value['ID'] => $value['TITLE']);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $max_current_commentsB; $i++)
        $columns += array('CB' . $i => 'Comment ' . $i);
    if (count($commentsB_select) && AllowEdit() && !isset($_REQUEST['_openSIS_PDF']))
        $columns += array('CB' . $i =>_addComment);
    $columns += array('COMMENT' =>_comment);
}


if(isset($_SESSION['GGG_FLAG']) && $_SESSION['GGG_FLAG'] == 1)
{
    foreach($stu_RET as $one_ret_key => $one_ret)
    {
        if(isset($import_RET[$one_ret['STUDENT_ID']][1]['GRADE_PERCENT']) && $import_RET[$one_ret['STUDENT_ID']][1]['GRADE_PERCENT'] != '')
        {
            $this_letter_grade = "<b>". _makeLetterGrade(($import_RET[$one_ret['STUDENT_ID']][1]['GRADE_PERCENT']/100)) ."</b>";
        }
        else
        {
            $this_letter_grade = "";
        }

        $stu_RET[$one_ret_key]['REPORT_CARD_GRADE'] = $this_letter_grade;
    }

    $_SESSION['GGG_FLAG'] = '';
    unset($_SESSION['GGG_FLAG']);
}


// echo "<pre>";print_r($stu_RET);echo "</pre>";

ListOutput($stu_RET, $columns,  _student, _students, false, false, array('yscroll' =>true));



if (count($stu_RET) != 0) {
    echo '<div class="panel-footer">' . SubmitButton(_save, 'submit[save]', 'class="btn btn-primary" onclick="self_disable(this);"') . '</div>';
}
echo "</FORM>";
echo '</div>'; //.panel-body
echo '</div>'; //.panel


function _makeGrade($value, $column) {
    global $THIS_RET, $current_RET, $import_RET, $grades_RET, $grades_select, $student_count, $tabindex;
    $tc_grade = 'n';
    if ($column == 'REPORT_CARD_GRADE') {

        if (!isset($_REQUEST['_openSIS_PDF'])) {
            $student_count++;
            $tabindex = $student_count;

            if ($import_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']]) {
                $select = $import_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['REPORT_CARD_GRADE_ID'];
                $extra_select = array($select => $grades_select[$import_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['REPORT_CARD_GRADE_ID']]);
                $div = false;
            } else {

                if ($current_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['GRADE_PERCENT'] != '') {

                    $select = _makeLetterGrade($current_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['GRADE_PERCENT'] / 100, "", User('STAFF_ID'), "%");
                }
                $rounding = DBGet(DBQuery('SELECT VALUE FROM program_user_config WHERE USER_ID=\'' . User('STAFF_ID') . '\' AND TITLE=\'ROUNDING\' AND PROGRAM=\'Gradebook\' AND VALUE LIKE \'%_' . UserCoursePeriod() . '\''));
                if (count($rounding))
                    $_SESSION['ROUNDING'] = rtrim($rounding[1]['VALUE'], '_' . UserCoursePeriod());
                else
                    $_SESSION['ROUNDING'] = '';

                if ($_SESSION['ROUNDING'] == 'UP')
                    $select = ceil($select);
                elseif ($_SESSION['ROUNDING'] == 'DOWN')
                    $select = floor($select);
                elseif ($_SESSION['ROUNDING'] == 'NORMAL')
                    $select = round($select);


                $dbf = DBGet(DBQuery('SELECT DOES_BREAKOFF,GRADE_SCALE_ID FROM course_periods WHERE COURSE_PERIOD_ID=\'' . UserCoursePeriod() . '\''));
                if ($dbf[1]['DOES_BREAKOFF'] == 'Y' && $select !== '') {

                    $get_details = DBGet(DBQuery('SELECT TITLE,VALUE FROM program_user_config WHERE USER_ID=\'' . User('STAFF_ID') . '\' AND PROGRAM=\'Gradebook\' AND VALUE LIKE \'%_' . UserCoursePeriod() . '\'  ORDER BY VALUE DESC '));
                    if (count($get_details)) {
                        $tgs_total = DBGet(DBQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) as RET_EX FROM program_user_config WHERE USER_ID=\'' . User('STAFF_ID') . '\' AND PROGRAM=\'Gradebook\' AND VALUE LIKE \'%_' . UserCoursePeriod() . '\''));
                        $tgs_total = $tgs_total[1]['RET_EX'];
                        $tgs_ac_total = DBGet(DBQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) as RET_EX FROM program_user_config WHERE USER_ID=\'' . User('STAFF_ID') . '\' AND PROGRAM=\'Gradebook\' AND VALUE LIKE \'%_' . UserCoursePeriod() . '\' AND VALUE IS NOT NULL'));
                        $tgs_ac_total = $tgs_ac_total[1]['RET_EX'];
                        if ($tgs_ac_total == $tgs_total) {
                            foreach ($get_details as $i => $d) {
                                $unused_var = explode('_', $d['VALUE']);
                                $unused_var2 = explode('-', $d['TITLE']);
                                if ($select >= $unused_var[0] && is_numeric($unused_var[0]) && $unused_var2[0] == UserCoursePeriod()) {
                                    $id = $i;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            $grade_id = explode('-', $get_details[$id]['TITLE']);
                            $select = $grade_id[1];
                        } else
                            $select = '';
                        $tc_grade = 'y';
                    }
                }

                if ($tc_grade == 'n')
                    $select = $current_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['REPORT_CARD_GRADE_ID'];
                $extra_select = array();
                $div = true;
            }
            if ($_REQUEST['modfunc'] == 'clearall')
                $select = '';

            $return = SelectInput($select, 'values[' . $THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID'] . '][grade]', '', $extra_select + $grades_select, false, 'tabindex=' . $tabindex, $div);
        }
        else {
            if ($import_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']])
                $select = $import_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['REPORT_CARD_GRADE_ID'];
            else
                $select = $current_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['REPORT_CARD_GRADE_ID'];
            $return = '<b>' . $grades_RET[$select][1]['TITLE'] . '</b>';
        }
    }
    elseif ($column == 'GRADE_PERCENT') {
        if ($import_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']])
            $select = $import_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['GRADE_PERCENT'];
        else {
            $select = $current_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['GRADE_PERCENT'];
            $rounding = DBGet(DBQuery('SELECT VALUE FROM program_user_config WHERE USER_ID=\'' . User('STAFF_ID') . '\' AND TITLE=\'ROUNDING\' AND PROGRAM=\'Gradebook\' AND VALUE LIKE \'%_' . UserCoursePeriod() . '\''));
            if (count($rounding))
                $_SESSION['ROUNDING'] = rtrim($rounding[1]['VALUE'], '_' . UserCoursePeriod());
            else
                $_SESSION['ROUNDING'] = '';

            if ($_SESSION['ROUNDING'] == 'UP')
                $select = ceil($select);
            elseif ($_SESSION['ROUNDING'] == 'DOWN')
                $select = floor($select);
            elseif ($_SESSION['ROUNDING'] == 'NORMAL')
                $select = round($select);
            $return = $select == '' ? '' : ($select + 0) . '%';
        }
        if ($_REQUEST['modfunc'] == 'clearall')
            $return = '<input type="hidden" name="values[' . $THIS_RET[STUDENT_ID] . '][percent]" value="" />';
    }

    return $return;
}

function _makeCAMarks($value, $column) {
    // Text input for user to enter CA marks
    return TextInput($value, "values[{$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']}][ca_marks]", '$value', 'size=4');
}

function _makeExamMarks($value) {
    // Text input for user to enter exam marks
    return TextInput($value, "values[{$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']}][exam_marks]", '', 'size=4');
}

function _makePercent($value, $column) {
    global $THIS_RET, $current_RET, $grades_RET, $student_count, $tabindex, $import_RET;

    if ($column == 'GRADE_PERCENT') {
        if (!isset($_REQUEST['_openSIS_PDF'])) {
            $student_count++;
            $tabindex = $student_count;
            if ($import_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']])
                $return = TextInput($import_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['GRADE_PERCENT'] == '' ? '' : (_makeLetterGrade($import_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['GRADE_PERCENT'] / 100, "", User('STAFF_ID'), "%") + 0) . '%', "values[$THIS_RET[STUDENT_ID]][percent]", '', (0 ? 'readonly ' : '') . 'size=6 maxlength=6 tabindex=' . $tabindex, false);
            else
                $return = TextInput($current_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['GRADE_PERCENT'] == '' ? '' : (_makeLetterGrade($current_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['GRADE_PERCENT'] / 100, "", User('STAFF_ID'), "%") + 0) . '%', "values[$THIS_RET[STUDENT_ID]][percent]", '', (0 ? 'readonly ' : '') . 'size=6 maxlength=6 tabindex=' . $tabindex, !$current_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['DIV']);
        } else
            $return = $current_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['GRADE_PERCENT'] == '' ? '' : (_makeLetterGrade($current_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['GRADE_PERCENT'] / 100, "", User('STAFF_ID'), "%") + 0) . '%';
    }
    elseif ($column == 'REPORT_CARD_GRADE') {
        if ($current_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['REPORT_CARD_GRADE_ID'] == '' && $import_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']]) {
            $return = '<b>' . $grades_RET[$import_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['REPORT_CARD_GRADE_ID']][1]['TITLE'] . '</b>';
        } else
            $return = '<b>' . $grades_RET[$current_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['REPORT_CARD_GRADE_ID']][1]['TITLE'] . '</b>';
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: What does "not able to" mean in specific terms? Explain what you expected to happen, in detail, and what actually happened when you ran the code, after having debugged it thoroughly to identify a clear issue. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue. Remember to provide relevant sample data so we can understand more easily what the code might do based on that data. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you define CA_MARKS and EXAM_MARKS in the `$columns` array right at the start of your posted code, and then try to add two more definitions for those same elements immediately afterwards? My quick test suggests this will have no effect, so which values do you actually want in there, the first pair or the second?

Comment: I want that on the User Interface under the CA marks column and exam Marks column the user should be able to input the marks on this table 
I defined two functions _makeCAMarks and _makeExam marks to make the fields of these column to be TextInput but it is not working and i got no error on my terminal